# Dynamic Google/OSM/Leaflet maps in EmberJs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ember.js, leaflet

I'm having this problem, I can set a map with a marker using emberjs like this

```
App.MapView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : "map",
    didInsertElement : function(){
    L.mapbox.accessToken = 'XXXXXXXXX';
   var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'XXXXXXX');

   L.marker([lat, lng],{
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post'})}).addTo(map);

}
});
```

But how can I set up custom map makers using EmberJs by using Latitude and Longitude data from a json dataset?

Although I prefer OSM and leaflet maps, Google maps is also fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at this: https://www.devmynd.com/blog/2014-1-using-emberleaflet-with-google-maps

It should answer all your questions.

Otherwise you could do it with a component as illustrated in: http://backstopmedia.booktype.pro/developing-an-emberjs-edge-special-code/8-embercomponent/